# How to Authenticate a SignalR Hub from Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

My Web API hosts SignalR also and Hub is decorated at class level using [Authorize] attribute.The Web API has implemented Basic Authentication and connections to the Hub routed through Controller action is working fine. My SignalR client is an MVC4 application in a different domain and I would like to connect to the Hub using Javascript / Jquery. As Hub level authentication is enabled, how do i authenticate the connection? My current client code is as follows

```
$.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:53256/signalr';
var myHub = $.connection.NewHub;


// Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
myHub.client.addMessage = function (name, message) {
...
}
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
myHub.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
});
```

Comment: When client tries to connect, it must get a http response with an authentication challenge and your browser should open a window asking for credentials. Do you see something different?

Comment: @Gustavo...no user intervention is possible, we have to supply credentials in header or some other way while establishing connection

Comment: Doing authentication across web servers is *always* non trivial as cookies don't flow between domains. You also can't set headers in the SignalR JS client since the websockets API doesn't support changing them.